# Unity3d не хочет компилировать .apk файл

Tags: android, android-sdk, unity3d

Вчера всё собиралось, потом открыл android studio, обновил все тулузы, на следующий день открываю unity, собираю .apk файл и ловлю ошибку "Android build CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to list target platforms. Please make sure the android sdk path is correct. See the Console for more details.
"

[image: Ошибка]

Думал что-то слетело, но нет. Android Studio собирает .apk файл исправно
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Вчера всё собиралось, потом открыл android studio, обновил все тулузы...

Логично значит сделать что? Правильно: понизить версии, то есть сделать downgrade  sdk tools к тем, что были или чуточку ниже, чем сейчас.

1. Идем в папку с android sdk tool и переименовываем её:

   ```
   [YourAndroidSDKRoot]/tools -> toolsXXXX
   ```
2. Скачивай старый SDK tools. Например если у тебя 25.3.0, то скачивай 25.2.5 (http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.5-windows.zip)
3. Извлеки данные в Android SDK
4. В *Unity* в настройках Edit → Preferences → External Tools еще раз проверь, что путь до Android SDK верный (Корректный путь до SDK, а не до папка *tools*)
5. Делай build проекта.

P.S. Вместо скачивания ZIP и распаковывания в директория возможно может помочь downgrade с помощью *SDK Manager*, который должен с SDK находится.

Comment: Да, на форуме юнити уже нашел этот ответ ( https://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1320861/android-build-commandinvokationfailure-unable-to-l.html )
ps не ожидал, что у юнити будут проблемы с новой версией софта

Comment: @ВладимирСалеев да мы вчера почти одновременно написали ответ. Я как раз дописывал его, когда ты свой опубликовал)) .... Ну может у новой версии будет норм всё. Но я бы не рекомендовал сразу после выхода новинки гнаться и тут же брать их. Можно же некоторое время выждать. А то всякое бывает.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ нашелся на https://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1320861/android-build-commandinvokationfailure-unable-to-l.html
Нужно поставить старую версию android sdk.
Так же была ещё одна ошибка (возможно только у меня), но всё же. Решил её так: minSDK = 19 API, targetAPI = 25